# How the Net RunRate for each team is calculated in IPL?

Tags: rules, cricket, statistics, indian-premier-league

> A team's net run rate is calculated by deducting from the average runs
>   per over scored by that team throughout the season, the average runs
>   per over scored against that team throughout the season. -[Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2013/engine/series/586733.html?view=pointstable)

I can't understand the above concept clearly.

Please, provide the exact formulas(ie, explain clearly) for calculating the net runrate in IPL with authentic references(with examples).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NRR for a team in cricket is calculated by the following formula

NRR = (Average runs scored per over by the team throughout the tournament) - (Average runs scored per over by the opposing teams against it).

Also Cricinfo , says the following rules are applied in case a match is abandoned/ concluded a duckworth lewis method.

> Where a match is abandoned, but a result is achieved under
>   Duckworth/Lewis, for net run rate purposes Team 1 will be accredited
>   with Team 2's Par Score on abandonment off the same number of overs
>   faced by Team 2. Where a match is concluded but with Duckworth/Lewis
>   having been applied at an earlier point in the match, Team 1 will be
>   accredited with 1 run less than the final Target Score for Team 2 off
>   the total number of overs allocated to Team 2 to reach the target.

Also only matches that never take place(abandoned without a ball being bowled) are not considered for the same i believe.

For example in current IPL , RCB has for and against values as (1046/133.0) and (1034/139.5) . So it would be (1046/133.0) - (1034/139.5) = 7.8644 - 7.4 = (approx) +0.470

Comment: Hi @kartshan

Can you explain D/L method with an example? Say, RR's score in current IPL is
 
Match 1: RR-125/9(20), OPP: 127/1(15.5)

Match 2: RR- 153/5(17.5), OPP: 60/4(6), RR won by 10 runs using D/L method.
Match 3:RR- 217/4(20), OPP: 198/5(20).
IPL point table is showing -0.247 run rate, but i am not sure , how it is calculated?

Answer (score 12):

The net run rate is calculated with the below formula:

```
NRR = ((Total runs scored by team)/(Total overs played by team))
        -
      ((Total runs scored against team)/(Total overs played against team))
```

**Total runs** -> This is straight forward. It is the score that a team scores (batting) and is scored against (bowling) in the whole tournament.

**Total overs** -> This is the total overs played (batting) and delivered (bowling) by a team. This one has a catch though.

- If a team is all out within the stipulated 20 overs, then the overs considered for NRR calculation is 20 itself and not the actual overs played.
- If a team chases down a target before 20 overs, then the actual overs is considered for NRR calculation.

Find below the current RCB Net Run Rate (0.47) and the break-up of how the figure has been arrived at considering all the games that they have played till now.

|  | RCB |  | Opponents |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Game #** | **Runs** | **Overs** | **Runs** | **Overs** |
| 1 | 156 | 20 | 154 | 20 |
| 2 | 130 | 20 | 130 | 20 |
| 3 | 162 | 17.4 | 161 | 20 |
| 4 | 158 | 17.3 | 154 | 20 |
| 5 | 165 | 20 | 166 | 19.5 |
| 6 | 152 | 20 | 152 | 20 |
| 7 | 123 | 17.5 | 117 | 20 |
| Totals | 1046 | 133 | 1034 | 139.5 |
|  | A | B | C | D |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  | RCB RR | A/B | 7.86 | E |
|  | Opponent's RR | C/D | 7.39 | F |
|  | **NRR** | E-F | **0.47** |  |

Answer (score 5):

Across the three games, TEAM1 scored 678 runs in a total of 147 overs and 2 balls (actually 147.333 overs), a rate of 678/147.333 or 4.602 rpo.

The run-rate scored against TEAM1 across the three games is calculated on the basis of 466 runs in a total of 50 + 50 + 50 = 150 overs, a rate of 466/150 or 3.107 rpo.

The net run-rate is, therefore, 
4.602 - 3.107 = + 1.495

NET RUN RATE OF TEAM1 is + 1.495

Answer (score 4):

The basic equation is as follows:

```
`Net run rate = (number of runs scored/number of overs faced) - (number of runs conceded/number of overs bowled)`
```

A positive net run rate means a team is scoring faster than its opposition overall, while a negative net run rate means a team is scoring slower than the teams it has come up against. A positive NRR is therefore desirable.

NRR is usually employed to rank teams that have finished a series or tournament on the same number of points.

Examples:
In the 2012 Indian Premier League (IPL), Pune Warriors scored 2321 runs off 319.2 overs and conceded 2424 runs off 310 overs. Pune Warriors' NRR is therefore:

```
(2321/319.333) - (2424/310) = 7.268 - 7.819 = -0.551
```

If a team is bowled out before completing their full quota of 20 or 50 overs (depending on whether it is a Twenty20 or one day match), that full quota is used in the net run rate calculation. For example, if the team batting first is bowled out for 140 after 35 overs of a 50-over game and the opposition reaches 141 in 32 overs, the NRR calculation for that match goes like this:

```
(140/50) - (141/32) = 4 - 4.406 = -0.406
```

Other Example:

New Zealand scores 1066 runs off 223 overs and conceded 974 runs off 238.2 overs. New Zealand's net run rate (NRR) is therefore calculated as follows:

```
(1066/223) - (974/238.333) = 4.780 - 4.086 = 0.694
```

Note: 238.2 overs, meaning 238 completed overs and two further balls, was converted to 238.333 for the purposes of calculation.

Hope this helps.