# How is the net run rate calculated if the match stopped due to rain?

Tags: rules, cricket, scoring, duckworth-lewis, interruption

Here we already discussed [how the net run rate is calculated](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/how-the-net-runrate-for-each-team-is-calculated-in-ipl).

If the match gets stopped due to rain, then how is the NRR calculated?

Consider both of these situations:

- Match stopped due to rain, but the result decided by DL method
- Match stopped without result after bowled a few overs in second innings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that net run rate is not part of the Laws, being only applicable to games played within a tournament, and so the precise method of calculation will depend on how the tournament specifies it (although I believe it remains virtually identical across tournaments, with possibly no changes at all). In the ICC Champions Trophy 2013, this is [how net run rate will be calculated in a D/L adjusted match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-champions-trophy-2013/content/page/634996.html):

> Only those matches where results are achieved will count for the purpose of net run rate calculations. Where a match is abandoned, but a result is achieved under Duckworth/Lewis, for net run rate purposes Team 1 will be accredited with Team 2's Par Score on abandonment off the same number of overs faced by Team 2. Where a match is concluded but with Duckworth/Lewis having been applied at an earlier point in the match, Team 1 will be accredited with 1 run less than the final Target Score for Team 2 off the total number of overs allocated to Team 2 to reach the target.

Answer (score 2):

In matches where Duckworth-Lewis revised targets are set due to interruptions which reduce the number of overs bowled, those revised targets and revised overs are used to calculate the net run rate for both teams.
    For example, in a 50-over World Cup first-round group match, Team A are dismissed for 165 in 33.5 overs.
    Team B progresses to 150-2, but play is halted after 26 overs due to rain. And the match never starts. The DL par score for team B is calculated as 149.
    Because the target was revised, and Team A were bowled out, Team A's total is reset to 149 from 44 overs, thus their RR = 149/44 ,approx 3.39. Team B's RR, however, is computed as normal:150/26.33 ,approx 5.70.
    Computing the match NRR for Team A gives us 3.39 - 5.70 = -2.31. Team B's NRR is: 5.70 - 3.39 = 2.31.

Answer (score 0):

During a D/L affected-result, the reduced target and overs are considered for NRR.
For instance, take up India vs Pakistan match in 2019 World Cup.

The scorecard reads:

India = 336/5 in 50 Overs
Pakistan = 222/6 (40)
India won by 89 Runs here according to D/l method.

Now the calculation will be,

D/L Target for Pakistan - 301 in 40 Overs,

So you should consider India's total as 300 in 40 Overs
Thereby, India Run Rate = 300/40 = 7.5
Pakistan Run Rate = 222/40 = 5.55

So, it is +1.95 for India and -1.95 for Pakistan

The NRR calculations for every scenario in Cricket is brilliantly depicted in [this blog](https://www.cricindeed.com/how-to-calculate-nrr-in-cricket/).