# In IPL match MI vs RR - who would enter into the playoff in case of "no ball"

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, indian-premier-league

During the IPL7 last league match between MI vs RR, the scores were leveled at 189.

Had the bowler bowled a *no ball* who would enter into the playoff, MI or RR?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the batsman get runs on No ball when the team requires only 1 run to win?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/does-the-batsman-get-runs-on-no-ball-when-the-team-requires-only-1-run-to-win)

Comment: @hims056, I think it's not a dupe.

Comment: @SportsFan: The question **was** a duplicate. I removed the duplicate question now so close vote as well. (You may edit out your answer as well)

Answer (score 5):

If Faulkner bowled a no-ball, [six runs would not be calculated](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/does-the-batsman-get-runs-on-no-ball-when-the-team-requires-only-1-run-to-win/2134#2134). The final score will be 190, not 195.

But still, Mumbai could qualify for the play-off matches. Since they need 190 in 14.3 overs, if 14.4 was a no-ball, then it won't be counted as a legal delivery.

Then the [Net run rate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/how-the-net-runrate-for-each-team-is-calculated-in-ipl) will be like below,

MI = **0.0135** (2175/271.2 - 2170/273.3)
RR = **0.0121** (2155/269.5 - 2159/272.5)

Mumabi Indians would lead RR in the Points table by just 0.0014 difference in NRR.